# Magento 2 - Include css from module in template

Tags: magento2, layout, template, css

I developed a new extension. I have some CSS which I need to include on some templates.

**CSS:**

> app\code\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\view\frontend\web\css\main.css

**Block:**

> \app\code\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\Block\Form.php

**Template:**

> app\code\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\view\frontend\templates\subscribe.phtml

The template is getting called in a CMS page:

```
{{block class="Fekete\Newsletter2Go\Block\Form" template="Fekete_Newsletter2Go::subscribe.phtml"}}
```

How can I include the CSS `main.css` in my template?

I solved it like this, it works... but in the developer documentation they say that we should not include css in the template.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl('Fekete_Newsletter2Go::css/main.css'); ?>"/>
```

Comment: Did you override template file or it will call in your controller?

Comment: No, I call the template in a cms page like this `{{block class="Fekete\Newsletter2Go\Block\Form" template="Fekete_Newsletter2Go::subscribe.phtml"}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add below code in your `router_controller_action.xml`  before body tag

```
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/filename.css" />
</head>
```

If it is a CMS page then you can add above code in CMS page layout update field

Comment: I have no `layout.xml` in my module. I created one `app\code\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\view\frontend\layout\layout.xml` and added your code above `<body>` but it does not work. Of course I modified it to match my scenario.

Comment: I had to rename `layout.xml` to `default.xml`, now it works

Comment: now it will be included on every page, if you want to include it on any particular page then you have to rename it to `router_controller_action.xml`

Comment: Oh ok I see. I have no controller for this though, it is only a template which I call in a cms page.

Comment: If it is a CMS page then you can add above code in CMS page  `Layout Update XML`  field